# PostgreSQL INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE (upsert) use all excluded values

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

When you are upserting a row (PostgreSQL >= 9.5), and you want the possible INSERT to be exactly the same as the possible UPDATE, you can write it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, username, password, level, email) 
                VALUES (1, 'John', 'qwerty', 5, 'john@mail.com') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
  id=EXCLUDED.id, username=EXCLUDED.username,
  password=EXCLUDED.password, level=EXCLUDED.level,email=EXCLUDED.email
```

Is there a shorter way? To just say: use all the EXCLUDE values.

In SQLite I used to do :

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tablename (id, user, password, level, email) 
                        VALUES (1, 'John', 'qwerty', 5, 'john@mail.com')
```

Comment: Not a real answer but you can use slightly shortly notation: 
`INSERT INTO tablename (id, username, password, level, email) VALUES (1, 'John', 'qwerty', 5, 'john@mail.com') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
 (username, password, level, email) = (EXCLUDED.username, EXCLUDED.password, EXCLUDED.level, EXCLUDED.email).` Almost the same, but easy to copy/paste/manage the column list

Comment: Another option is to use jsonb columns and that way you don't have to worry about columns

Comment: @foal post that as an answer, it is quite a useful alternative.

Comment: You don't need to update `id`, since it is the same (conflict field). That makes it a bit shorter.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Postgres hasn't implemented an equivalent to `INSERT OR REPLACE`. From the [`ON CONFLICT` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) (emphasis mine):

> It can be either DO NOTHING, or a DO UPDATE clause specifying the **exact details** of the UPDATE action to be performed in case of a conflict.

Though it doesn't give you shorthand for replacement, `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` applies more generally, since it lets you set new values based on preexisting data. For example:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, level)
VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET level = users.level + 1;
```

Comment: Can you expand on "but the exact issue in the insert did not cause the update"?

Comment: @pojo-guy - I don't think you saw the question from MrR - Can you expand on "but the exact issue in the insert did not cause the update"?

Comment: When you attempt to use insert ... on update in postgresql, the results are different under some specific circumstances than a merge. The case I ran into was rather obscure and specific, but it was repeatable.  It's been a few months, so I can't give any more rightnow.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't a conflict but another error e.g. field type error?

Comment: @Kristján does the users.level takes from what is in DB (let's assume 5) or is it based on the corresponding value given for the level field which is 0 in this case? If there is conflict what will be the new value 6 to 1?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately there isn't a shorter way to write that. You MUST specify each column you want to update in the `do update` section.

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (id, username, password, level, email, update_count) 

-- if id doesn't exist, do insert
VALUES (1, 'John', 'qwerty', 5, 'john@mail.com', 0) 

-- how to check for duplicates (more versatile: could use any unique index here)
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO UPDATE 
SET 
  -- update duplicate clause
  username=EXCLUDED.username, -- references proposed insertion row
  password=EXCLUDED.password,
  level=EXCLUDED.level,
  email=EXCLUDED.email,
  update_count=tablename.update_count+1 -- reference existing row
```

`on conflict` will give you something similar to `insert or replace` from sqlite, but it's a more versatile function that is more focused on `update` rather than just a full row replace.

Comment: Upvote for pointing out how to reference the existing row