# insert overwrite table in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, syntax, amazon-redshift

I want to fully overwrite a Redshift table.

In e.g. Hive, I could do the following:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO target 
SELECT s.* FROM staging s LEFT JOIN target t
ON s.primaryKey = t.primaryKey AND s.distKey = t.distKey
WHERE t.primaryKey IS NULL;
```

I don't get this to work in Redshift (other than dropping and re-creating the table).

Does anybody know what the Redshift syntax is for overwrite?

Comment: last time I checked postgreql didn't have an overwrite clause of INSERT

Answer (score 5):

While there is no command equivalent to `INSERT OVERWRITE`, you can do this via:

- `TRUNCATE <table>`
- Use `SELECT INTO`

eg: `SELECT <column> INTO <table> FROM <etc>`

The `TRUNCATE` command is a very efficient way to delete all contents of a table. However, it cannot be reversed by a `ROLLBACK`, so make sure you really want to do it!

See:

- [TRUNCATE documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRUNCATE.html)
- [SELECT INTO documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_INTO.html)

Comment: Modern pg v9.5+ can use *ON CONFLICT* rules ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36360189/287948))