# Updating another table on conflict postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement to insert on one table (test01) and update on another table(result) whenever the conflict arises. I tried with below query:

```
insert into test01 as cst (col1,col2) 
select col1,col2 from (
select 1 col1,'test' col2) as excluded
on conflict (col1) do 
   update result as rst set conflictid = excluded.col1, updated_at = now() where rst.conflictid= excluded.col1 ;
```

but its returns "syntax error at or near result". Can anyone please help me with the right solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359440/postgresql-insert-on-conflict-update-upsert-use-all-excluded-values

Comment: @Roopesh Thanks for your reply. My requirement here is to update another table when the conflict arises.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your approach is not feasible. The `ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` clause applies **only** to the table into which the rows are inserted. See [INSERT syntax in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

A solution requires a bit more work. You should create a trigger for table `test01` to get the effect you want.

Example tables (slightly changed names of columns and table):

```
create table test01_conflicts(
    conflict_id int primary key, 
    updated_at timestamp);

create table test01(
    id int primary key, 
    str text);
```

When the table `test01` is updated with the same `id` the trigger function inserts or updates a row in the conflict table. Note that in this case the function returns `null` so the update on `test01` will not proceed.

```
create or replace function before_update_on_test01()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if new.id = old.id then
        insert into test01_conflicts(conflict_id, updated_at)
        values (new.id, now())
        on conflict(conflict_id)
        do update set updated_at = now();
        return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_update_on_test01
before update on test01
for each row execute procedure before_update_on_test01();
```

The query. On conflict update `test01` with the same `id` only:

```
insert into test01
select col1, col2 
from (
    select 1 as col1, 'test' as col2
    ) as source
on conflict (id) do 
    update set
    id = excluded.id;
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. I tested it and it works. I wonder if this workaround has any performance drawbacks or not.

Comment: @FarzadSoltani - Of course, massive inserts with frequent conflicts will be slower but the only additional cost is to update the auxiliary table.

Comment: I think if they added a `ON CONFLICT DO IF .....  THEN UPDATE ....` syntax it would eradicate the need for such complex logic handling.

Comment: You cannot use `IF` in this context. Only `DO NOTHING` or `DO UPDATE SET`.

Comment: Yes, that's the current unfortunate state.