# I am getting the error subquery must return only one column when I try to run the following query:

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, pgadmin-4

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE checkUpdateAdd(imei1 inout text, assetName1 inout text)
language 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
declare
begin
    PERFORM * from msdata;
if (select * from msdata where imei = imei1) then
    --UPDATE "public"."msdata"
    UPDATE public.msdata SET assetname1 = assetname where imei = imei1;
    -- return assetname;
-- SELECT * FROM msdata ORDER BY imei ASC;
elseif (select * from msdata where imei != imei1) then
    Insert into public.msdata(imei,assetname) values (imei1,assetname1);
    --return;
end if;
    -- return (null,null);
end;
$BODY$;

call checkUpdateAdd('123','abc1');
SELECT * FROM msdata;
```

where `msdata` is an existing table with columns `imei` and `assetname`.

So now if I have to create a procedure  which on calling - creates or updates the msdata

Comment: Can you pls. explain what do you want to achieve? Is it that if imei1 exists in the table then return the value associated with it, otherwise create a new record (imei1, assetname1)? Or update assetname if imei1 if exists?

Comment: imei and assetnumber are the coloumns in table - ms data

I want to create  query which - 
has 2 conditions - 
1st being ---> if imei = imei1 then asset number changes
2nd being ---> if imei =! imei1 then new row gets created with new imei and asset number

Comment: I see. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather create a function that updates or inserts and returns the old value of `assetname` field upon update or `null` (as there is no old value) upon insert. Please note the [FOUND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) predefined variable.

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION checkUpdateAdd(imei1 text, assetName1 text)
returns text language plpgsql AS
$BODY$
declare
  retval text;
begin
  select assetname into retval from msdata where imei = imei1;
  if FOUND then -- (imei = imei1) exists, return the old assetname value
    update msdata SET assetname = assetname1 where imei = imei1;
    return retval;
  else
    insert into msdata(imei, assetname) values (imei1, assetname1);
    return null;
  end if;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Btw. if `imei` is a primary key or if it has an `unique` constraint then the task becomes much more simple. You ca use [insert on conflict do update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359440/postgresql-insert-on-conflict-update-upsert-use-all-excluded-values) and do not need a function or procedure.

**Update** As a procedure:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE checkUpdateAdd(imei1 text, assetName1 text) 
language plpgsql AS
$BODY$
begin
  if exists (select from msdata where imei = imei1) then
    update msdata SET assetname = assetname1 where imei = imei1;
  else
    insert into msdata(imei, assetname) values (imei1, assetname1);
  end if;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Thank u so much. 
but what is the major reason behind not choosing a PROCEDURE?

Comment: A function can be used in expressions. Well, more or less it's a matter of personal preference too. Do you accept the answer?

Comment: I will have to add a procedure or a function because we need the logic initially so that later we can upload.csv files and this function can be used

Comment: Good point, it makes sense to encapsulate & reuse.

Comment: Well I completely agree with you about personal preference, but it is said that function has to return but procedure doesn't.

I was wondering how can it be implemented in procedure.

Comment: Well at a very basic level procedures are routines that do things, functions are routines that get things. If you have a piece of code that does both (out or in out parameters) then ask your  self "Is this piece of code doing multiple thing, if so can/should it be separated into multiple routines of code"?